# "tube" vs. "tubing"

Tags: etymology, morphology

I have always run into word twins like **tube** vs. **tubing**.

More pairs: **fence** vs. **fencing**, **pipe** vs. **piping**, **cable** vs. **cabling**, **rail** vs. **railing**, etc.

This is an interesting phemonenon. Most of these nouns cannot function as verbs, but adding the *ing*-form generates a new word with a similar meaning.

Can you please explain the morphology behind this? Does the *ing*-form bring with it a different connotation? Any nuances between these twins?

Comment: It needs to be noted that there is not necessarily a "good reason" or "rule" to distinguish when one term is used vs the other.  Rather, the traditions that have arisen in the associated trades are a major determiner of which is used.  Eg, "tube" can be used for a stiff cylinder, whereas "tubing" is almost always flexible.

Answer (score 3):

From the Wiktionary article on "**[-ing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ing#Suffix)**":

> Suffix **-ing**: Used to form uncountable nouns from various parts of speech denoting materials or systems of objects considered collectively.
>   ***Roofing*** is a material that covers a roof.
>   ***Piping*** is a system of pipes considered collectively.

See the suffix *-ing* has three actions, according to Wiktionary:

1. Forming gerunds - from verbs, obviously
2. Forming the nouns to designate something "collectively", as in your examples
3. Forming nouns of the action or the procedure of a verb ("the *forging* of the sword took hours")

Comment: I agree, but it's not the whole picture, I'm afraid. Sometimes nouns with the *ing*-form don't necessarily function as collective nouns.

Comment: @KinzleB - interesting. So sometimes a noun-derived noun ending with *ing* will be a count noun? P.S. found it - **railing** is a count noun indeed.

Comment: Of course. There are numerous examples. e.g. "Could have been a real mess around here if I didn't have that tubing for tourniquets." quotation from *Sin City*

Comment: @KinzleB but then they function as count nouns they still imply "a collection" or "a length" of something, an amount significant in quantity and/or more complex than the parent word.

Comment: @KinzleB, Copperkettle,  Ah but the issue with railing is that *rail* and *railing* don't refer to the same thing at all, so they aren't the same type of example. *Fencing* refers to fences in general, *piping* to pipes, tubing to tubes: but railing does not refer to rails. It's not the same use of the suffix :) [Interesting question and nice answer btw!]

Comment: @Araucaria -  But aren't *(hand)rails* synonymous with *railing*? Oh, "rail" is possibly different since "rails" in the sense "handrails" are used in the plural. But still: *(hand)rails* consist of rails, and more elaborate (hand)rails, or handrails in a "bigger amount" tend to be called railing (probably).

Comment: We never go to buy a load of "railing" for the new houses being built as we might go to buy a coil of tubing. There is no class "railing".

Answer (score 0):

Here is another common way these words are used:

> When they put the roof on the warehouse, they went with metal roofing.
>
> When you're repairing an air conditioner or the built-in chilled-water
>   dispenser of a fridge, you may need to cut off a section of copper
>   tubing, to replace a leaky tube.
>
> We needed to repair the fence where the cattle had broken through the
>   split-rail fencing.
>
> When you ice the cake, use chocolate icing.

NOTE: We would go to buy 100 foot of copper tubing or a 100-foot roll of cyclone fencing but *not* a 100 foot of copper *piping. We buy 100 foot of copper *pipe*. Piping refers to the installed system of pipes.