# What is the difference between 'tube' and 'tubing' in technical writing?

Tags: differences

I write technical documentation. Our products include fluid conduits. People call them tubes, tubing, hoses, lines. When would the word tube be insufficient and tubing be required?

Comment: "Tubing" is generic, in the sense that one might have roll of tubing that is cut into individual pieces.  The individual pieces, once they have a "life of their own", are "tubes".

Comment: @HotLicks Interesting; it sounds the other way to me. *Tube* is generic - anything from pasta to fancy water slides. [*Tubing*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tubing), on the other hand, refers more specifically to conduits used in various 'apparatus'.

Comment: Thanks for catching my error, @PhilSweet. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can refer to this: ["tube" vs. "tubing"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214504/tube-vs-tubing)

Suffix -ing: Used to form uncountable nouns from various parts of speech denoting materials or systems of objects considered collectively.

tube - a conduit (channel to transfer liquid)

tubing - a system of tubes considered collectively

Comment: “ tube - a conduit (channel to transfer liquid)” // As far as I know, actually pipes are used to channel fluids (liquids and gases), while pipes are used as supports and structures (for example to house wires).